# PCI Errors being Spammed

Tags: pci

Have just installed a new Ubuntu build and I am getting spammed with the following pci errors. There are so many I cannot even get to the command prompt to even try and fix it. I have tried ignoring the errors using the following in the grub file

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"

However this appears to have done nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: pci errors]

[image]

Comment: You seem to have a hardware problem, that may be structural for your motherboard. Can you add `pci=nommconf` to the grub cmdline?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added pci=nommconf as you asked but the error persists. This the one I am now currently getting spammed with

Comment: Have you tried an alternate boot - perhaps from the Ubuntu live DVD/USB?

Comment: The second screenshot seems to indicate that `0000:61:00.1` is your on-board soundcard. Can you disable it in UEFI? Was the card working before? Can you boot with something else (e.g. a live distro from an USB stick), and verify if you are getting the same errors, and if the card still works?

Comment: Didn't need sound on this rig so I had already disabled the sound card along with the wireless and bluetooth in the Bios. I completely forgot to mention I am using a short pcie 4.0 riser cable from the motherboard to the graphics card so it might be related? I will try  booting from a live distro as you have mentioned and see if that works. I do appreciate everybody's help